# holding old goose version while run test case in go lang

Tags: golang-migrate

**Firstly I created some migration and their goose version is 20220125506 something like that but afterwords I add some new migration files but my goose version does not change every time while running the test case. How do I change my goose version? is there any hope please give me a solution.**

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the schema before running the test to try to run all migrations each time you run the test migration.